# Fargate public ip yields ECONNREFUSED or ETIMEDOUT

Tags: docker, rest, express, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am in the following situation:

I have created a small express.js application with an Alive endpoint, as following:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: "Alive"
  });
});

app.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  logger.info("Running on ECR through Fargate")
});
```

I have successfully created a Docker image via my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm i
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

When I run the image locally

```
docker run -d --publish 5000:5000 <name>
```

It works perfectly

[image]

I then proceed to upload my image to my ECR repository after I have tagged it with "latest". I have created a cluster and a task defition.

Task defition:

- Task memory (MiB)1024
- Task CPU (unit)512
- Compatible with Fargate
- Host  Port: 5000
- Container Port: 5000
- Protocol: tcp

If I go into my cluster and take a look under the logging I see the following message:

[image]

Which is my start-up message. So everything -seem- to work absolutely fine. But when I use postman to send a GET to my task's public IP I get either an ECONNREFUSED or ETIMEDOUT.

I can't work out what I am doing wrong, I have followed a bunch of tutorials online and I am very sure I have done exactly like they do. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the Security Group associated to your Task ENI does not allow port 5000 through from ANY source? That would be the most common mis-configuration.

Comment: You absolute madlad, you did it. You solved my issue. Biggest thanks!

Comment: Please make a separate answer so I can mark as solved and upvote even further!

Comment: Cool. Happy to hear you solved it. I made it a separate full answer for others to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in the thread, the issue was that that the Security Group associated to the Task ENI did not allow port 5000 through from ANY source.